# How do I pick a word that's next to a number in a file in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say that I open this file (wordlist.txt):

```
...
14613 bore
14614 borg
14615 boric
14616 boris
14621 born
14622 borne
14623 borneo
14624 boron
...
```

How do I pick the word next to it, if a variable is, for example, 14623?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just doing this once, do it the way falsetru showed.

If you need to look up multiple numbers, store the entries in a dictionary:

```
wordmap = {}
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        wordmap[key] = value
```

Now you can look up any number like this:

```
>>> wordmap['14623']
borneo
```

A few refinements you might want to add:

1. `rstrip` the newline off the end of the word
2. `split(None, 1)` to handle words with spaces in the middle of them
3. `wordmap[int(key)]` so you can look up `wordmap[14623]` instead of `wordmap['14623']`
4. Rewrite the whole thing as a two-liner with a comprehension
5. Better error handling, so if a line in the file is invalid, you can skip it, or print a useful error message like "Invalid line #1731: `'glassdfefewasd'` instead of dumping a generic exception, or whatever is appropriate.

For example, this does #1, #2, and #4:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    wordmap = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in f)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner and (negligibly) more efficient if `row = line.split()` was `k, v = line.split()`?

Comment: @RussW: I don't know (or really care) if it would be more efficient, but you're right, it is cleaner (and I think the error messages on invalid lines will even be slightly better). I'll edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RussW: OK, I guess I do care a little. :) From a quick test in CPython 3.3.0, that change does reduce the time from 60.8us to 59.8us. So, your guess was right. But replacing the whole thing with a genexp passed to dict (which is sort of doing the equivalent of `row[0]` and `row[1]`, but in C…) reduces it to 54.3us. Of course you're already right that it's cleaner, and that that's more important, but it's nice to know you're right about the other part too, right? :)

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        if row[0] == '14623':
            print(row[1])
            break
```

Comment: To avoid unnecessary splits do `if line.startswith('14623 '):` and then split inside the if-statment.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That only avoids unnecessary splits by doing the same work two different ways, which I think makes things more complicated and for what's probably a small and rarely-relevant performance benefit.

Comment: @abarnert:  How does it do the work two different ways?  `if line.startswith('14623 '):print line.split()[1]` doesn't look more complicated to me.  I do agree that it's "probably a small and rarely-relevant performance benefit."

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: It has to read over `'14623 '` to (effectively) see if the part before the space matches `'14623'` in the `startswith' call, and it has to read over the same prefix again to find the space and split on it. (It's not the "wasted performance" of scanning it twice—your version probably is faster, and it probably doesn't matter; it's the fact that conceptually you're repeating yourself, doing two different things that have to have the same effect.) Anyway, either one is readable _enough_, but I think falsetru's way is a little more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is very readable if you only want to access the item once:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print next(line.split()[1] for line in f 
               if line.startswith('14623'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

line_num = 14615
print re.search(r''+str(line_num)+' (\w+)', file_text).group()
```